# Limiting distribution of first order statistics ${X}^{n}$

Tags: order-statistics

[Question from "Introduction to probability and mathematical statistics" by Bain and Engelhardt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD4jp.png)

Salutations! I am attempting the problem above.Specifically I am having a problem with part c). I do not understand how the answer at the back of the book was arrived at. Could you please help me figure it out. the answer given is $$0 \, \text{for} \, y \le 1 \\  1-\frac{1}{y} \, \text{for} \, y\gt 1 \\$$
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. So just in case anyone struggles with the same problem her is the solution. 
$$F_{X_{1:n}}(x) = P[X_{1:n}\le x]\\ = 1-P[X_{1:n} \gt x]\\= 1- P[Min(X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n}) \gt x] \\ =1- P[X_{1}\gt x, X_{2} \gt x,...,X_{n} \gt x] \\ 
=\prod_{i=1}^nP[X_{i:n} \gt x]  = 1-[1-F(x)]^n = 1 - (1-(1- \frac{1}{x}))^n \\
= 1 - \frac{1}{x^n} $$
Thus the limit of this goes to 1 as n goes to $\infty.$ Similarly for part c) we have that:
$$F_{X_{1:n}^n}(x) = P[X_{1:n}^n\le x]\\ = P[X_{1:n} \le x^{1/n}]\\
= 1 - (x^{1/n})^{-n} = 1- \frac{1}{x} $$

Hence the limit of this expression stays the same when n approaches $\infty$.